# How can I Select typefaces to suggest historic or cultural context?

Tags: typography

I want information about historic or cultural context in choosing typeface

Comment: I can only recommend one book but it is in Spanish: https://www.google.com/search?q=30+siglos+de+tipos+y+letras

Comment: I think you need to narrow your question down. Are you looking for specific suggestions, or are you asking in general how typography relates to its historical context?

Answer (score 1):

Typography always will be subjective and like almost all kind of visual communication system, can adopt abstract ways to communicate intentions.

That said, look for communication and graphic design history. A books like "Meggs' History of Graphic Design" is a good *timelined* source of information that you can synchronize with your project's historichal time. Research about the typeface history. For instance, when you know that Trajan Typeface is related with ancient roman columns, you will think twice before using it to project a communication piece about ancient England history.

Cultural contexts can be target with some vernacular typography research. You can make your own research, going out and looking for facades, posters and billboards around community area your project intent to achieve, you can look in sites like [Vernacular Typography Project](http://www.vernaculartypography.com/), or others like this.